# Jquery works strangely on large monitor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website I have a div that stretches 400% of the screen. When the website loads the main divs position is 0. When I click a button it measures the width of the Html document and moves the div left 100% of the width of the screen. This works on my mac computer, on google chrome, safari, and firefox. It also works on a windows with google chrome. But when I try it on a large monitor it doesn't work. The monitor I am trying it on is a TV. What happens is when I click the button it measures 100% of the html document and I get 1805px but then it moves the div 100% to the left so it should move it 1805px to the left but it moves it 1804.99 pixels to the left.

Here is my java code

```
$('#bottom_logo').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

            var position = ($('#main_div_wide_wrapper').position().left) *-1;
            var width = $( document ).width();


            $('#main_div_wide_wrapper').animate({
                'left' : '+=' + width + 'px' //moves left
                }, 1000);


    });//end bottom_logo
```

Comment: Is it just me, or `position` isn't really used anywhere in this code?

Comment: Is width() coming back with the correct value? Or is the animation stopping short?

Comment: Position is not used, I just have it there and put it in an alert() so I could see what its value was. But the width() is coming out as the correct value. But when it moves the width of the screen I get its position and the position should be the same as the width of the screen but its coming out as 1804.99 instead of 1805